# Google translator issue in my website

Tags: google-translator-toolkit

I have integrated google translator in my websites.
It was working fine. But since Dec 1st it is not working for any lanuguages.

Is there any problem in script or any changes in google code ?

Thank you for looking into that.

script js : 
http://jquery-translate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.translate-1.3.2.min.js

Comment: It doesn't show any error. But it is not working when choosing a different languages.

I have added the above js file only.

Comment: "not working" isn't a problem description. Without seeing your code/setup, no one can help you with as little information as that. You'll need to do at least some debugging yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I have used the following codes.
Here are my script:
jQuery(function(){var langname="id";
if(langname=="ar"){ jQuery('body').translate( { from: 'en', to: 'ar', fromOriginal: true} );
} else if(langname=="fr"){
 jQuery('body').translate( { from: 'en', to: 'fr', fromOriginal: true} );
} else if(langname=="id"){
 jQuery('body').translate( { from: 'en', to: 'id', fromOriginal: true} );
} else {
 jQuery('body').translate( { from: 'en', to: 'en', fromOriginal: true} );
}
});

Answer (score 0):

Google translate service is now available as a paid service only, see below.

> Important: Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service
>   only, and the number of requests your application can make per day is
>   limited. As of December 1, 2011, Google Translate API v1 is no longer
>   available; it was officially deprecated on May 26, 2011. These
>   decisions were made due to the substantial economic burden caused by
>   extensive abuse. For website translations, we encourage you to use the
>   Google Website Translator gadget.

.